# Sequelize query works with sqllite but not with mssql

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sqlite, typescript, sequelize.js

I have the following sequelize function:

```
console.log(arr[index + 1], period, type, line, cell, site)
return db.History.findAll({
    where: {
        createdAt: {
            $lt: arr[index + 1],
            $gt: period
        },
        type: type,
        '$Line.name$': line
    },
    attributes: [[sequelize.fn('AVG', sequelize.col('value')), 'value']],
    include: [{
        model: db.Line,
        include: [{
            model: db.Cell,
            where: { name: cell },
            include: [{
                model: db.Site,
                where: { name: site }
            }]
        }]
    }]
```

In my Chai Unit tests, this db query executes as expected and returns the correct values, here is an example of the values logged out:

```
moment("2017-03-02T07:00:00.000") moment("2017-03-02T06:00:00.000") 'oee' '602' 'Powders' 'Ashford'
moment("2017-03-02T08:00:00.000") moment("2017-03-02T07:00:00.000") 'oee' '602' 'Powders' 'Ashford'
moment("2017-03-02T09:00:00.000") moment("2017-03-02T08:00:00.000") 'oee' '602' 'Powders' 'Ashford'
moment("2017-03-02T10:00:00.000") moment("2017-03-02T09:00:00.000") 'oee' '602' 'Powders' 'Ashford'
moment("2017-03-02T11:00:00.000") moment("2017-03-02T10:00:00.000") 'oee' '602' 'Powders' 'Ashford'
moment("2017-03-02T12:00:00.000") moment("2017-03-02T11:00:00.000") 'oee' '602' 'Powders' 'Ashford'
```

However, when I am testing this in "real life", I am getting the error:

> RequestError: Column 'Histories.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

these are example of the queries logged out:

```
[1] moment("2017-06-01T01:00:00.000") moment("2017-06-01T00:00:00.000") 'oee' '604' 'powders' 'Ashford'
[1] moment("2017-06-01T02:00:00.000") moment("2017-06-01T01:00:00.000") 'oee' '604' 'powders' 'Ashford'
[1] moment("2017-06-01T03:00:00.000") moment("2017-06-01T02:00:00.000") 'oee' '604' 'powders' 'Ashford'
[1] moment("2017-06-01T04:00:00.000") moment("2017-06-01T03:00:00.000") 'oee' '604' 'powders' 'Ashford'
[1] moment("2017-06-01T05:00:00.000") moment("2017-06-01T04:00:00.000") 'oee' '604' 'powders'
```

I can't see any difference between the parameters used in the unit tests and with the real life use. My unit tests use a `sqllite` db whereas the real life use, uses `mssql` aside from that I can't see any difference.

Any ide what is causing this?

Comment: This error is the result of testing in one DBMS and deploying to another. sqllite does not require you to group by every column not part of an aggregate function but sql server does.

Comment: @SeanLange I see, so how should I modify my query to avoid this issue?

Comment: I don't know anything about sequelize and the syntax is not exactly intuitive. You need to include Histories.id in the group by or make that column an aggregate (min, max).